# How to set accessible name for any QLabel in Qt which we can read using windows Narrator

Tags: c++, windows, qt, accessibility, qlabel

I am trying to set `AccessibleName` for QLable, we have a function but its not working

```
ui->label->setAccessibleName("My name is Dnyaneshwar");
```

I'm using same for `QPushButton` and its  working

Answer (score 2):

Setting the text browser interaction on the label makes it work:

```
ui->label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
```